# mpv fails to play youtube videos

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube-dl, mpv, youtube

I've been using mpv for a while, but now whenever I try to play a youtube video the following output shows up:

```
[ffmpeg] https: HTTP error 403 Forbidden
Failed to open https://rr5. . .
EDL: Could not open source file: 'https://rr5. . .'
No video or audio streams selected.
```

Oddly, I can play videos on other platforms, such as Odysee and Rumble. I've looked for answers in this substack and elsewhere and haven't found a solution for this specifically.

Comment: Please provide full commands you are using to download/play video.

Comment: I'm using the usual ones: $mpv <url>. Now the problem is different. The error message is now

``[ffmpeg] tcp: Connection to tcp://www.youtube.com:443 failed: Permission denied
Failed to open <url>.
[ytdl_hook] ERROR: [youtube] IcQZSrHtzMs: Unable to download API page: <urlopen error [Errno 13] Permission denied> (caused by URLError(PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied'))) 
[ytdl_hook] youtube-dl failed: unexpected error occurred´´